# Why does my sleeping bag say "Collect [enter number here] Survivor Points" when I try to wait till day or wait till night on Dying Light?

Tags: dying-light

When I try to wait till day or wait till night at my sleeping bag, it will occasionally say "Collect [enter random number here] Survivor Points"... Why does it do this?  I have only seen it a few times, but when I do see it, it's a really crazy number (like in the hundred-thousand to ten-millions range).
I have already done plenty of research on this topic, but as far as i can tell, nobody else has seen this.

Comment: If I remember right, at night you passively earn points just for being outside. Those are collected when you go inside or when you rest. I've never seen it in the hundreds of thousands, though - usually 1000 or less.

Comment: I don't really want to put it as an answer because I don't know what's going on with your crazy huge numbers. Hopefully someone else can shed some light on that.

Comment: please set this as an answer, because I have been losing reputation points for not accepting an answer on this question.  I have to accept something.

Comment: You absolutely do not lose rep for having an unanswered question. I'm not sure what's costing you rep, but it's not that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Chris mentioned, you do earn points passively for being outside at night. You also earn them for doing various things. If you kill enemies of any kind, parkour/agility maneuvers, or escaping volatiles etc. When you choose to sleep until day at the sleeping bag you are both ending the night, and securing your survivor points.

They are called survivor points because you are surviving, if you chose to stay out, you can earn more, but you are risking your life more, hence when you die you lose a large sum of survivor points.

It only says collect points if you have points to collect. 
This is only a night time mechanic and you shouldn't be seeing it when you sleep until night. It's because you earn 2x more points at night so you lose them if you don't secure them (again by sleeping or just surviving the night).

As for seeing 100,000-1,000,000 points... I have no idea and that's definitely a unique thing. I've racked up a lot of points before by running around killing volatiles but I don't ever recall hitting a million. But I guess it's a possible number to reach.

Comment: thank you @n_palum!  I earn lots of survivor points at night because I have the following, and I just drive around in fields, hitting volatiles.  I also like to shoot them with my gold-tier engraved semi-automatic shotgun (it's a one-shot kill gun).  that would probably explain the large numbers.  If you would like to know how to get the shotgun i use, i would be happy to let you know.

Comment: No problem @Horus. And I used to do the same thing, me and a friend would just mow them down with cars and the shoot them with bows. Following is a great DLC.

Comment: yeah im glad i finally got it lol

Comment: did you want me to tell you how to get the shotgun?

Comment: I haven't touched the game in a month so I'm okay, thanks though